# merging csv files into one sheet and obtaining the timestamp and file name of each csv file on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have successfully merged multiple csv files. I am now trying to take the filename and created timestamp of each imported csv file and place the filename and created time stamp into a separate sheet in a specific cell. This would list the files I have merged by filename and created timestamps.

I thought I can add some type of code into the loop. I am just not sure on the syntax to use for the timestamp and filename. I am not sure if this can be done either? Does anyone know the syntax or code to use that I can add into the loop, that would list the time stamps and file names of each imported csv file into a separate sheet? I have tried different codes, but it keeps crashing. Below is the loop that is successfully merging multiple files. If you have any questions, please let me know.

```
    Dim wbout   As Workbook
    Dim wsMstr  As Worksheet
    Set wsMstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lfileCSV    As String
    Dim fList As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim FileChosen As Integer
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wbCSVDisplayOrder As Long
    Dim M As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'start the OUT file listing
    fCSV = Dir(fName & "test*.CSV")
    RowInsert = 2

    Do Until fileCSV = ""
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fileCSV)
        With wbCSV.Worksheets(1)
            LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A2:FG" & LastRow).Copy
            wsMstr.Range("A" & RowInsert).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            wbout.Close False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            RowInsert = RowInsert + LastRow - 1
        End With
        fileCSV = Dir()
    Loop
```

The expected results would insert the created timestamp and the filename of each imported csv file into a cell in a different sheet. An example, if you imported three csv files then the filename and timestamp for each of csv file will be listed on another sheet.

Thank you

Comment: Time stamp of when the files were merged or when the files were created? For creation  you can get the data with `FileDateTime(fileCSV)` and format the string with `Format()` or `mid, trim, left, right` whatever works

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Power query for this task?
With power query you can get data from folder.
With few simple transforms. It will combine the csv. Files and get the time date stamp amongst other things